# Converting a python code to MATLAB

Tags: python, matlab

I'm trying to rewrite some python code in MATLAB, the python code is like this :

```
theta = 0:pi/510:2*pi;
phi   = pi/3:2*pi/360:6*pi;
phi_outer = np.linspace(CV.Outer.phi_min, CV.Outer.phi_max, 100)
phi_inner = np.linspace(CV.Inner.phi_max, CV.Inner.phi_min, 100)

x1, y1 = coords(phi_outer, geo, theta, CV.Outer.involute)
t = np.linspace(0,1,100)
x3, y3 = coords(phi_inner, geo, theta, CV.Inner.involute)
x2 = (x3[0]-x1[-1])*t+x1[-1]
y2 = (y3[0]-y1[-1])*t+y1[-1]
x4 = (x1[0]-x3[-1])*t+x3[-1]
y4 = (y1[0]-y3[-1])*t+y3[-1]
```

My attempt at a MATLAB conversion:

```
theta = 0:pi/510:2*pi;
phi   = pi/3:2*pi/360:6*pi;
phi_outer = linspace(CV.Outer.phi_min, CV.Outer.phi_max, 100);
phi_inner = linspace(CV.Inner.phi_max, CV.Inner.phi_min, 100);
[x1, y1] = coords(phi_outer, geo, theta, CV.Outer.involute);    
[x3, y3] = coords(phi_inner, geo, theta, CV.Inner.involute);
t =  linspace(0,1,100);
x2 = (x3(2)-x1(1)).*t+x1(1);
y2 = (y3(2)-y1(1)).*t+y1(1);
x4 = (x1(2)-x3(1)).*t+x3(1); 
y4 = (y1(2)-y3(1)).*t+y3(1);
```

`X2`, `y2`, `x4`, `y4` are absolutely not correct but I did not understand what´s mean here  `x3 [0] -x1 [-1]`) ... So in MATLAB the array starts with `x3(1)` not `x3(0)` and there is nothing like `x1(-1)` as I know.
can someone please explain it to me and maybe suggest to me how should I rewrite the `x2`, `y2`, `x4`, `y4`.

Comment: Python enumeration starts with 0. If you don't know how long the list (or whatever) is, -1 selects the last item in the sequence.

Comment: `x[-1]` means the last value of the array. In Matlab, you can convert it to `y3(end)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax `x[-1]` indexes the *last element* in the array in Python.

To achieve this in MATLAB you can use the `end` keyword

```
x(end)
```

Answer (score 1):

MATLAB indexing starts at `1`, not at `0` like python's. So it'd be

```
x2 = (x3(1)-x1(end)).*t+x1(end);
y2 = (y3(1)-y1(end)).*t+y1(end);
x4 = (x1(1)-x3(end)).*t+x3(end); 
y4 = (y1(1)-y3(end)).*t+y3(end);
```

where each element basically is indexed as `MATLABindex = PythonIndex-1`, and, as mentioned by others already, MATLAB's way of selecting the last element in an array is `end`